# How to prove law of tangent using vector method

Tags: geometry

I saw the proof of law of tangent using trigonometry. There are also proofs for law of sine and cosine using vector methods. Can somebody tell me how to get the proof of law of tangent using vectors?

Geometrical interpretation of law of sines is area of a parallelogram and for law of cosine its geometrical interpretation is projection. What is the geometrical interpretation of law of tangents?

Comment: what is the law of tangent ? Can you state it for me please ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents